# Driving RGB LED with Constant Current Driver - Only Blue Working

Tags: led, constant-current

I am driving a common anode [RGB LED](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=1082299&library=usen&tab=1) using a 15mA [constant current LED driver](https://learn.adafruit.com/tlc5947-tlc59711-pwm-led-driver-breakout/overview). What really confuses me, is that only the blue light works when plugged in. The red and green ones seem to be dead. Whenever the lead for Red or Green is plugged in, the voltage across either would drop from ~5V to ~0V. I haven't written any code yet, and need help in debugging the LED behavior.

Any input would be appreciated!

The red and green lights are still functional, as I can light them up by tuning a dc power supply. However, they wouldn't light up when connected to the constant current driver.

[image]

Comment: You'd need to supply a schematic showing how you wired it up. We can't guess. There's a schematic button on the [edit]or toolbar.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: added Fritzing:)

Comment: That's a *wiring diagram* rather than a schematic and it doesn't show us the *schema* of your design. Those Fritzing diagrams are often called "cartoons" around here. It doesn't show us the function of the LED pins, the function of the pins on the blue board or the green board. To make sense of it we have to research three documents to understand the pinout. Fritzing may be able to export a proper schematic for you to upload.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the feedback! will do a proper update

Comment: I think as you draw the proper schematic it may reveal some errors in your thinking or your wiring. It should make it much clearer to you how the circuit is supposed to work.

Comment: That makes sense :) Fritzing does provide a proper schematic as shown above. My guess is that the LED itself is flimsy as I could not figure out issues in circuit itself.

Comment: That Fritzing "schematic" is only a slight improvement over the previous picture.  It appears you have the cathode of the blue LED connected to +5V, and the comon anode of the LEDs and the red and green cathodes all connected to PWM pins - something is definitely wrong with the LED connections.

Comment: Why do you have your LEDs' common-anode connected to the PWM22 pin, and the cathode of the Blue LED connected to V+?

Comment: The schematic is unreadable in its current form, please fix it

Comment: @Transistor You are definitely right in that drawing the schematic help clarify things up! I should have picked up paper and pencil and gone through the process myself.

Comment: @VoltageSpike thanks for the feedback. i clearly underestimated the importance of drawing readable schematics.

Comment: @brhans  Thanks for catching that. I realize I messed up the RGB LED pins in Fritzing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's tidy up.

[image]

1. Rotate 90° anti-clockwise.
2. Rotate 90° anti-clockwise.
3. Show your power supply ground connection. You can use GND symbols for everything connected to GND and eliminate some wiring to tidy up your schematic.
4. Show your power supply + connection.
5. Untangle the wires here. Can you see anything odd with the wiring of the three LEDs? (I can.)
6. Sort out this neatly.

Try and make your schematics read neatly from left to right. Positive voltages go to the top and negative or ground to the bottom of the drawing. That's why, when you rotate the board schematics so that the text is the right way up you'll find the GNDs at the bottom and V+ at the top. The LEDs are the right way up.

Tidy up the wiring and add the new diagram to your post to show your progress.

When you do this the reason for your problem should become apparent.